# How to vectorize a function with array lookups

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize my fitness function for a Minimum Vector Cover genetic algorithm, but I'm at a loss about how to do it.

As it stands now:

```py
vert_cover_fitness = [1 if self.dna[edge[0]] or self.dna[edge[1]] else -num_edges for edge in edges]
```

The `dna` is a one-dimensional *binary* array of size `[0..n]`, where each index corresponds to a vertex, and its value indicates if we have chosen it or not. `edges` is a two dimensional *positive integer* array, where each value corresponds to a vertex (index) in `dna`. Both are `ndarray`s.

Simply explained - if one of the vertices connected by an edge is "selected", then we get a score of one. If not, the function is penalized by `-num_edges`.

**I have tried** `np.vectorize` as an attempt to get away cheap with a lambda function:

```py
fit_func = np.vectorize(lambda edge: 1 if self.dna[edge[0]] or self.dna[edge[1]] else -num_edges)
vert_cover_fitness = fit_func(edges)
```

This returns `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.`, as this function is applied to each *value*, and not each row.

To fix this I tried `np.apply_along_axis`. This works but it's just a wrapper for a loop so I'm not getting any speedups.

If any Numpy wizards can see some obvious way to do this, I would much appreciate your help. I'm guessing a problem lies with the representation of the problem, and that changing either the `dna` or `edges` shapes could help. I'm just not skilled enough to see what I should do.

Comment: I wish both `vectorize` and `apply...` had stronger speed disclaimers.  `vectorize` has on, but buried in a note at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with this bit of numpy code, it runs 30x faster than your for loop on my randomly generated data.

```
import numpy as np
num_vertices = 1000
num_edges = 500
dna = np.random.choice([0, 1], num_vertices)
edges = np.random.randint(0, num_vertices, num_edges * 2).reshape(-1, 2)

vert_cover_fitness1 = [1 if dna[edge[0]] or dna[edge[1]] else -num_edges for edge in edges]

vert_cover_fitness2 = np.full([num_edges], -num_edges)
mask = (dna[edges[:, 0]] | dna[edges[:, 1]]).astype(bool)
vert_cover_fitness2[mask] = 1.0

print((vert_cover_fitness1 == vert_cover_fitness2).all()) # this shows it's correct
```

Here is the timeit code used to measure the speedup.

```
import timeit

setup = """
import numpy as np
num_vertices = 1000
num_edges = 500
dna = np.random.choice([0, 1], num_vertices)
edges = np.random.randint(0, num_vertices, num_edges*2).reshape(-1, 2)
"""

python_loop = "[1 if dna[edge[0]] or dna[edge[1]] else -num_edges for edge in edges]"

print(timeit.timeit(python_loop, setup, number=1000))

vectorised="""
vert_cover_fitness2 = np.full([num_edges], -num_edges)
mask = (dna[edges[:, 0]] | dna[edges[:, 1]]).astype(bool)
vert_cover_fitness2[mask] = 1.0
"""

print(timeit.timeit(vectorised, setup, number=1000))

# prints:
# 0.375906624016352
# 0.012783741112798452
```

Comment: Wow, great solution Addy. I made my own in the meantime, taking tips from https://medium.com/@TejasBob/being-efficient-with-numpy-part-1-2e13f783f41b.
Yours is almost twice as fast however! Thank you. Is it possible to learn this power..?

Comment: Well, this was the first implementation that came to mind really, so we might be just lucky that its relatively fast. However, when designing vectorised algorithms that contain if statements, my way of addressing that is to generate an int mask that contains 1 where the condition met, 0 otherwise and then simply create the result as `result = (condition) * result_true + (1 - condition) * result_false`. This is usually much faster than iterating over each element separately. The code above is a variant of this as we generate all the conditions into `mask` and then write 1.0 where satisfied.